# Unable to re-publish Shiny app to ShinyApps.io

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have had a working and published shiny app for a couple of years now. I made some edits to the app (and also updated to the latest R and Rstudio) and it still runs perfectly in the Rstudio environment but I am unable to re-publish it externally. When attempting to do so I get the following error:

```
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 1352279461 failed: Error building image: Error building MASS (7.3-60). R version 4.3.2 currently unavailable
```

Full deployment log attempt below. I think upgrading to R version 4.3.2 may have actually hurt me here?

```
── Preparing for deployment ────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔ Re-deploying "binomial-probability" to "server: shinyapps.io / username: amorris412"
ℹ Looking up application with id "10410243"...
✔ Found application <https://amorris412.shinyapps.io/binomial-probability/>
ℹ Bundling 2 files: app.R and temp_plot.png
ℹ Capturing R dependencies with renv
✔ Found 57 dependencies
✔ Created 42,078b bundle
ℹ Uploading bundle...
✔ Uploaded bundle with id 7886767
── Deploying to server ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Waiting for task: 1352279452
  building: Processing bundle: 7886767
  building: Building image: 9443497
  building: Building package: MASS
## Begin Task Log ##############################################################
## End Task Log ################################################################
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 1352279461 failed: Error building image: Error building MASS (7.3-60). R version 4.3.2 currently unavailable
Execution halted
```

The app runs fine in Rstudio as you can see in the background of the screenshot. I am simply trying to republish

[Publish to Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foh2T.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an option for you, but sometimes it is helpful to completely delete the shiny app remotely on [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io). Maybe you can also get away with renaming it remotely, so you have a backup.

Then also remove all local files associated with the previous deployment.

Then redeploy it as a fresh new app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad someone else is having this problem. I just switched to Eye Holes and couldn't deploy an app today, so I think that must be the problem. I'm using a Mac, and apparently RSwitch can use older versions for specific instances. But I can't make heads or tales of it. I'm thinking about reverting to 4.3.1 til Posit gets the kinks out. It looks like this problem of deployment with new versions has happened a few times in the past.